kivy python, with a spinner dropdown widget problem
I have created a calendar in kivy python, with a spinner dropdown widget that calculates the number of hours worked that day. The problem I have is that I can't set the font to 30. I've tried kowntless examples and descriptions I found online, but none of it works.
here is the sinner:
def show_osark_dialog(self):
# Create a popup window for OSARK
osark_popup = Popup(title='Matematik', size_hint=(None, None), size=(700, 400), auto_dismiss=True)
    # Content layout for the popup
    osark_content = GridLayout(cols=1, padding=10, spacing=10)
    
    # Create spinners for selecting times
    time_spinner1 = Spinner(text='00:00', values=[f'{h:02d}:{m:02d}' for h in range(24) for m in range(0, 60, 15)])
    time_spinner2 = Spinner(text='00:00', values=[f'{h:02d}:{m:02d}' for h in range(24) for m in range(0, 60, 15)])

    # Function to calculate time difference
    def calculate_time_difference(instance, value):
        time1 = datetime.strptime(time_spinner1.text, '%H:%M')
        time2 = datetime.strptime(time_spinner2.text, '%H:%M')
        time_diff = abs(time2 - time1)
        osark_label.text = f'Jobbade timmar: {time_diff}'

    # Bind the calculate_time_difference function to spinner values change
    time_spinner1.bind(text=calculate_time_difference)
    time_spinner2.bind(text=calculate_time_difference)

    # Label to display the time difference
    osark_label = Label(text='Välj start och sluttid ...')
    
    # Add spinners and label to the content layout
    osark_content.add_widget(time_spinner1)
    osark_content.add_widget(time_spinner2)
    osark_content.add_widget(osark_label)

    # Set the content of the popup window
    osark_popup.content = osark_content

    # Open the popup window
    osark_popup.open()

How do I get font 30 in this dropdown widget?

I added the full code ...

The Spinner class by default uses the SpinnerOption class to represent the options. However, you can specify your own option class using the option_cls property.
For example, here is an option class possibility:
class MySpinnerOption(Button):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MySpinnerOption, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.font_size = 30
        self.size_hint_y = None
        self.height = 30

Then you can specify the new option class when you create the Spinner:
time_spinner1 = Spinner(text='00:00', values=[f'{h:02d}:{m:02d}' for h in range(24) for m in range(0, 60, 15)], option_cls='MySpinnerOption')

If you want the base of the Spinner to have the same font size, just add font_size=30 to the Spinner. See the documentation.

Thank you for your answer.
I looked at your code and tried to implement it, but just get errors. I am a beginner and just getting started with this code base, so I have a hard time debugging a code I don't understand. But if you look at my code above, how would you have implemented your code in this situation?.
It might be easier for you if you see my whole code:
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.spinner import Spinner
from kivy.clock import Clock
import calendar
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import webbrowser

# ___________________________________________________________________________________________

SPREADSHEET_ID = '----------'
API_KEY = '---------'

# Define credentials JSON data
credentials_json = {
    "type": "service_account",
    "project_id": "timmraport",
    "private_key_id": "-------",
    "private_key": "-----",
    "client_id": "--------",
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/timraport%40timmraport.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}

# Authorize using credentials
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_dict(credentials_json, scope)
client = gspread.authorize(credentials)


# Access the spreadsheet ------------------------------------------------------------
spreadsheet = client.open_by_key(SPREADSHEET_ID)

class CalendarApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.year = 2024  # Initial year
        self.month = 1    # Initial month
        self.cal = calendar.monthcalendar(self.year, self.month)
        self.today = datetime.now().day  # Get today's day
        
        layout = GridLayout(cols=7, padding=1, spacing=1)
        self.update_calendar(layout)
        return layout
    
    def update_calendar(self, layout):
        layout.clear_widgets()
        days = ['Mo', 'Ti', 'On', 'To', 'Fr', 'Lö', 'Sö']

        # Add day labels
        for day in days:
            label = Button(text=day, background_color='#1c99e0', font_size=60)
            layout.add_widget(label)

        # Add day buttons
        for week in self.cal:
            for day in week:
                if day == 0:
                    layout.add_widget(Button(text='', background_color=(0.09, 0.1, 0.15, 0)))
                else:
                    btn = Button(text=str(day), background_color='#171a27', font_size=50)
                    if self.is_date(day):
                        btn.border = (1, 1, 1, 1)
                        btn.border_width = (0.5, 0.5)
                    if day == self.today:  # Highlight today's date
                        btn.background_color='#c86fff'  # Change to the specified color
                    btn.bind(on_press=lambda instance, day=day: self.show_popup(day))
                    layout.add_widget(btn)
                    
    def is_date(self, day):
        # Check if a given day is within the month's days
        if day in range(1, calendar.monthrange(self.year, self.month)[1] + 1):
            return True
        return False
        
    def show_popup(self, day):
        self.popup = Popup(title='Datumet du valt att ändra är:  ' + str(day),
                           size_hint=(None, None), size=(700, 450),
                           auto_dismiss=False)
        content = GridLayout(cols=1, padding=10, spacing=10)
        
        # Text input for number
        self.number_input = TextInput(hint_text='Skriv in dina timmar ...', font_size=50)
        content.add_widget(self.number_input)
        
        # Dropdown list
        dropdown = DropDown()
        for option in ['Normal arbetstid', 'Övertidstimmar', 'Storhelgstillägg']:
            btn = Button(text=option, size_hint_y=None, height=110, background_color='#ffffff', font_size=30)
            btn.bind(on_release=lambda btn: dropdown.select(btn.text))
            dropdown.add_widget(btn)
        
        main_button = Button(text='Arbetstider', size_hint=(None, None), size=(310, 80), background_color='#a2a3ac', font_size=30)
        main_button.bind(on_release=dropdown.open)
        dropdown.bind(on_select=lambda instance, x: setattr(main_button, 'text', x))
        
        # Create a nested GridLayout for buttons
        buttons_layout = GridLayout(cols=2, spacing=10)
        
        # Add the main button and the link button
        buttons_layout.add_widget(main_button)
        
        # Add open popup"
        link_button = Button(text='Ändra inlagda tider', size_hint=(None, None), size=(310, 80), background_color='#a2a3ac', font_size=25)
        link_button.bind(on_release=lambda instance: self.show_text_popup())
        buttons_layout.add_widget(link_button)
        
        content.add_widget(buttons_layout)
        
        # Buttons layout
        buttons_layout = GridLayout(cols=2, spacing=1)
        
        # OK button
        ok_button = Button(text='OK', background_color='#171a27', font_size=40)
        ok_button.bind(on_press=lambda instance: self.add_to_google_sheets(day, main_button.text))
        buttons_layout.add_widget(ok_button)
        
        # Cancel button
        cancel_button = Button(text='Avbryt', background_color='#171a27', font_size=40)
        cancel_button.bind(on_press=self.cancel_popup)
        buttons_layout.add_widget(cancel_button)
        
        content.add_widget(buttons_layout)

        # Button to open OSARK dialog
        osark_button = Button(text='---  Matematik  ---', background_color='#171a27', font_size=20)
        osark_button.bind(on_press=lambda instance: self.show_osark_dialog())
        content.add_widget(osark_button)
        
        self.popup.content = content
        self.popup.open()
    
    def show_text_popup(self):
        # Create a popup window for text information
        text_popup = Popup(title='Information', size_hint=(None, None), size=(700, 450), auto_dismiss=True)

        # Create a GridLayout for the content of the popup
        text_content = GridLayout(cols=1, padding=10, spacing=10)

        # Text input for information
        text_input = TextInput(text="Önskar du att ändra i dina inlagda arbetstider, kan du bara skriva in din nya tid, och din gamla tid skrivs då över. Önskar du att radera tiden helt, kan du NOLLA UT din inskrivna tid med en '0' nolla. Då raderas tiden het från kalendern för den dagen.",
                           font_size=25, halign='left', readonly=True, multiline=True, size_hint_y=800)
        text_input.bind(minimum_height=text_input.setter('height'))
        text_content.add_widget(text_input)

        # Create a GridLayout for buttons
        buttons_layout = GridLayout(cols=3, spacing=10, size_hint_y=None, height=80)

        # Create a button to clear the calendar data
        clear_button = Button(text="Rensa kalendern", background_color='#171a27', font_size=25)
        clear_button.bind(on_release=self.clear_calendar_data)
        buttons_layout.add_widget(clear_button)

        # Add "BI BI" button next to "Rensa allt i min kalender" button
        bi_bi_button = Button(text="Timmarraport", background_color='#171a27', font_size=25)
        bi_bi_button.bind(on_release=lambda instance: webbrowser.open("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xQV_e_kmp9-ECTVX-9pAP4u4F1ug0JFD58vCRWgc5vE/export?format=pdf"))
        buttons_layout.add_widget(bi_bi_button)

        # Add KUCOS button
        kucos_button = Button(text="Min lön", background_color='#171a27', font_size=25)
        kucos_button.bind(on_release=lambda instance: self.show_kucos_popup())
        buttons_layout.add_widget(kucos_button)

        # Add buttons layout to the content layout
        text_content.add_widget(buttons_layout)

        # Set the content of the popup window
        text_popup.content = text_content

        # Open the popup window
        text_popup.open()

    def show_osark_dialog(self):
        # Create a popup window for OSARK
        osark_popup = Popup(title='Matematik', size_hint=(None, None), size=(700, 400), auto_dismiss=True)
        
        # Content layout for the popup
        osark_content = GridLayout(cols=1, padding=10, spacing=10)
        
        
        # Create spinners for selecting times
        time_spinner1 = Spinner(text='00:00', values=[f'{h:02d}:{m:02d}' for h in range(24) for m in range(0, 60, 15)])
        time_spinner2 = Spinner(text='00:00', values=[f'{h:02d}:{m:02d}' for h in range(24) for m in range(0, 60, 15)])

        # Function to calculate time difference
        def calculate_time_difference(instance, value):
            time1 = datetime.strptime(time_spinner1.text, '%H:%M')
            time2 = datetime.strptime(time_spinner2.text, '%H:%M')
            time_diff = abs(time2 - time1)
            osark_label.text = f'Jobbade timmar: {time_diff}'

        # Bind the calculate_time_difference function to spinner values change
        time_spinner1.bind(text=calculate_time_difference)
        time_spinner2.bind(text=calculate_time_difference)

        # Label to display the time difference
        osark_label = Label(text='Välj start och sluttid ...')
        
        # Add spinners and label to the content layout
        osark_content.add_widget(time_spinner1)
        osark_content.add_widget(time_spinner2)
        osark_content.add_widget(osark_label)

        # Set the content of the popup window
        osark_popup.content = osark_content

        # Open the popup window
        osark_popup.open()

    def show_kucos_popup(self):
        try:
            # Retrieve data from Google Sheets
            worksheet = spreadsheet.get_worksheet(0)
            data_h41 = worksheet.acell('H41').value
            data_h43 = worksheet.acell('H43').value
            data_i43 = worksheet.acell('I43').value

            # Create a popup window for KUCOS information
            kucos_popup = Popup(title='Information', size_hint=(None, None), size=(700, 350), auto_dismiss=True)

            # Create a GridLayout for the content of the popup
            kucos_content = GridLayout(cols=3, padding=10, spacing=10, )

            # Add text to the GridLayout
            kucos_content.add_widget(Label(text="Mina timmar", color=[49/255, 227/255, 191/255, 1], font_size=35))
            kucos_content.add_widget(Label(text="Innan skatt", color=[49/255, 227/255, 191/255, 1], font_size=35))
            kucos_content.add_widget(Label(text="Min lön ut", color=[49/255, 227/255, 191/255, 1], font_size=35))

            # Add retrieved data to the GridLayout
            kucos_content.add_widget(Label(text=data_h41, font_size=40))
            kucos_content.add_widget(Label(text=data_h43, font_size=30))
            kucos_content.add_widget(Label(text=data_i43, font_size=30))

            # Set the content of the popup window
            kucos_popup.content = kucos_content

            # Open the popup window
            kucos_popup.open()
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error fetching data:", e)

    def cancel_popup(self, instance):
        self.popup.dismiss()

    def add_to_google_sheets(self, day, column):
        try:
            number = self.number_input.text.replace(',', '.')  # Replace comma with dot for decimal values
            number = float(number)  # Convert to float
            
            # Check if a choice has been made in the dropdown menu
            if column == 'Arbetstider':
                # Show error message if no choice has been made
                self.number_input.text = 'Välj typ av arbetstider !!! ...'
                return

            # Calculate the row number based on the day selected
            row = 8 + day
            
            # Determine the column index based on the selected option
            if column == 'Normal arbetstid':
                column_index = 4  # Column D
            elif column == 'Övertidstimmar':
                column_index = 5  # Column E
            elif column == 'Storhelgstillägg':
                column_index = 6  # Column F
            
            # Select the first worksheet
            worksheet = spreadsheet.get_worksheet(0)
            # Update the cell with the calculated row and column index
            worksheet.update_cell(row, column_index, number)
            
            # Close the popup window
            self.popup.dismiss()
            # Refresh the calendar layout
            self.update_calendar(self.root)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error adding data to Google Sheets:", e)

    def clear_calendar_data(self, instance):
        try:
            # Select the first worksheet
            worksheet = spreadsheet.get_worksheet(0)
            # Clear all data in the worksheet
            worksheet.clear()
            # Close the popup window
            instance.parent.parent.parent.dismiss()
            # Refresh the calendar layout
            self.update_calendar(self.root)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error clearing calendar data:", e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    CalendarApp().run()

